# admin-ajax.php not working properly on subdomains

Tags: plugins, ajax, cookies

I am trying to multiply product price (pulled from database) by, corresponding to switched language, cookie-stored currency. To achieve this I am using AJAX script and several methods. Problem is with method `currencyRates();`

Although in test environment everything is working fine (instead of subdomains I use subfolders), on production level method `currencyRates();` is simply returning value 1 (initialized at the beginning of the method, when I `var_dump $rate` in foreach loop, it gives me expected value but when i try to return it is always value of initialized at the beginning variable `$rate = 1`).

What's happening? How subdomains can affect this type of script? Values from database are correct, the problem is only with `currencyRates();` returning initial value or zero when return is used inside foreach loop.

I tried moving whole method to `get_original_price();` method but then AJAX response is returning 0 instead of `product_price` multiplied by currency.

Take a look, if you need more code I can paste but I'm almost sure everything else is working fine (I get response, only multiplied by 1 because of `$rate = 1`).

```
    public function get_original_price() {
        global $post;
        $variation_id = $_POST['variation_id'];
        $original_price = get_post_meta($variation_id, "_regular_price", true);

        $ratesCurrency = $this->currencyRates();
        $priceAfterCurrency = $original_price*$ratesCurrency;
        echo $priceAfterCurrency;
        wp_die();

    }

        private function currencyRates() {

        global $wpdb;
        $rate = 1;

        $currency = $_COOKIE['wcumcs_user_currency_session'];

        $name = 'wcumcs_exchange_rate_'.$currency;

        $selectRate = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."options WHERE option_name='".$name."' LIMIT 1;");

        foreach ($selectRate as $row) {
          $rate = $row->option_value;    
        }
        return $rate;
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a REST-API endpoint instead of admin-ajax? :)

Comment: Never heard of it but I will take a look, thanks. No ideas why it's happening? @JackJohansson

Comment: REST API endpoints have much fewer pitfalls and traps, and are more straight forward and easier to test

Comment: @Soothsayer92 are you moving from subdomain to subdomain? And how are your cookies set? Have you considered passing the values rather than relying on the cookies?

Comment: @TomJNowell I think one of the reasons that people are not using REST as they should is the response type. Everyone can use an `echo` in AJAX, and it can be read by everyone and everything ( including SE ), however to use REST you need to handle the JSON.

Comment: Javascript and pretty much everything handles JSON just fine, and for simple values such as strings and numbers it's a non-issue, but lets not discuss the merits of REST APIs here, comments are for clarifying questions and answers about the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother with the complicated cookie/ajax nonsense, use a REST API!

We'll use dependency injection and RESTful APIs to remove the cookies and simplify your AJAX code.

First things first, lets turn this into a REST API:

```
class Stuff {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
                register_rest_route( 'soothsayer/v1', '/current_rate/', array(
                        'methods' => 'GET',
                        'callback' => [ $this, 'get_original_price' ]
                ) );
        } );
    }

    public function get_original_price( $request ) {
        $variation_id = $request['variation_id'];
        $original_price = get_post_meta( $variation_id, "_regular_price", true);

        $currency = $request['currency'];

        $ratesCurrency = $this->currencyRates( $currency );
        $priceAfterCurrency = $original_price*$ratesCurrency;
        return $priceAfterCurrency;
    }

    private function currencyRates( $currency ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $rate = 1;

        $name = 'wcumcs_exchange_rate_'.$currency;
        $selectRate = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."options WHERE option_name='".$name."' LIMIT 1;");

        foreach ($selectRate as $row) {
            $rate = $row->option_value;    
        }
        return $rate;
    }
}
```

Now we have a REST endpoint! Notice how I:

- Fixed the indenting, or rather my editor did it automatically without effort, and so should yours!
- Used dependency injection to grab the currency. `currencyRates` doesn't need to know where the currency value came from, it's passed as a parameter, now it'll work for any currency no matter how it was acquired, not just the one set in the cookie
- Currency is now a parameter, javascript can read cookies just fine, and now your request is 100% cachable. This is now 1000% better for performance
- Notice the `$request` object passed into `get_original_price`, this will give you all the details

### How do I use this?

```
jQuery.get(
    'https://example.com/wp-json/soothsayer/v1/current_rate',
    {
        'variation_id' => 1,
        'currency' => 'USD'
    },
    function( data ) {
        // success?
    }
);
```

Or even by visiting `https://example.com/wp-json/soothsayer/v1/current_rate?variation_id=1&currency=USD`

### An Optimisation

This is not how you fetch an option from the options table:

```
    global $wpdb;
    $rate = 1;

    $name = 'wcumcs_exchange_rate_'.$currency;
    $selectRate = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."options WHERE option_name='".$name."' LIMIT 1;");
```

This is how you do it:

```
$rate = get_option( 'wcumcs_exchange_rate_'.$currency, 1 );
```

If you need to fetch multiple options you can do that via `get_option` with no parameters to grab an array

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I am trying to implement this to my single-product page. So far I've managed to get restful API working under URL but I have some questions. How can I display a result of the API on my product page? Also, how can I pass which currency is stored in cookies at the moment? @TomJNowell

Comment: The first question is a standard JS/JQuery question, it's just a standard GET request so I won't cover that, plenty of tutorials do it far better than I could including jquery.com, and the latter I recommend looking up jQuery cookie, but I would question if cookies are really the best way to store this data